# pass a command line argument to jvm(java) mapper task

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to debug some parts of my mapper for which I need to pass some command line arguments to the jvm(java) process which starts the mapper. What are the different ways to do this?

I figured out one way to change MapTaskRunner.java, but I want to avoid compiling the whole hadoop package. There should be some simple way using a configuration file to pass extra command line arguments to the jvm mapper process.

Comment: I do not understand how could you achive debug with another arguments, can you give an example.

Comment: Well, jprofiler requires me to add some command line arguments in order to debug through their debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the following configuration in mapred-config.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx4096m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC</value>
</property>
```

In value part you may set your arguments using `-D`.

Alternatively you may set the `HADOOP_OPTS` in your terminal:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5000"
```

For more info on local debugging hadoop jobs, see [here](http://amnigos.com/post/44631353593/how-to-guide-hadoop-mapreduce-debugging-in-lo).