# Including ThirdParty JAR in Hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, jar

I have a custom (Mahout) class that I am trying to run via Hadoop. I have followed the instructions [here](http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/) (as well as one comment to put the jars in HDFS) but I keep getting the following error

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.common.AbstractJob
```

My setup is as follows:

```
    REP_ROOT=/home/user/.m2/repository
    MAHOUT_CORE=$REP_ROOT/org/apache/mahout/mahout-core/0.9/mahout-core-0.9.jar
    MAHOUT_CLI=$REP_ROOT/org/apache/mahout/commons/commons-cli/2.0-mahout/commons-cli-2.0-mahout.jar
    MAHOUT_INTEGRATION=$REP_ROOT/org/apache/mahout/mahout-integration/0.9/mahout-integration-0.9.jar

    LANG3=$REP_ROOT/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
    GOOGLE_LIST=$REP_ROOT/com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/guava-14.0.1.jar

    export LIBJARS=$MAHOUT_CORE,$MAHOUT_CLI,$MAHOUT_INTEGRATION,$LANG3,$GOOGLE_LIST
    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$MAHOUT_CORE:$MAHOUT_CLI:$MAHOUT_INTEGRATION:$LANG3:$GOOGLE_LIST

    hadoop jar /home/user/bin/CustomJar.jar com.company.Mahout.LDAJob \
   -libjars ${LIBJARS} \
    -DbaseLocation=/user/hadoop/test \
    -Dinput=input \
   -Doutput=output
```

The missing class (AbstractJob) is in the included in MAHOUT_CORE. The LDAJob starts as:

```
public class LDAJob extends AbstractJob{

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    ToolRunner.run(conf,new LDAJob(), args);
}

public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {    
    Configuration conf = super.getConf();  
    String baseFileLocation = conf.get("baseLocation");
.....
}
```

Details of error

```
    14/02/26 01:29:44 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
14/02/26 01:29:44 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/02/26 01:29:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201402260118_0004
14/02/26 01:29:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/02/26 01:29:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201402260118_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(CombineFileRecordReader.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(CombineFileRecordReader.java:126)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.MultipleTextFileInputFormat.createRecordReader(MultipleTextFileInputFormat.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(CombineFileRecordReader.java:155)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mahout/common/AbstractJob
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.WholeFileRecordReader.<init>(WholeFileRecordReader.java:61)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.common.AbstractJob
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 28 more
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the declaration of your LDAJob class (the line with `class LDAJob implements BlahBlah`, etc.).

Comment: sure. it's as follows: public class LDAJob extends AbstractJob implements Tool

Comment: Well that didn't help.  You may get more insight if you pass `-verbose:class` to java opts on your task node, and then you can look at the logs there to see what's going on.

Comment: BTW, to do what I just suggested, see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286333/pass-a-command-line-argument-to-jvmjava-mapper-task .

Comment: there is a huge amount of info. Searching for word "Mahout" I see the following     attempt_201402260006_0001_m_000000_0: [Loaded org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectoryMapper from file:/home/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201402260006_0001/jars/]

attempt_201402260006_0001_m_000000_2: [Loaded org.apache.mahout.text.WholeFileRecordReader from file:/home/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201402260006_0001/jars/]

Comment: what is not clear is why SequenceFilesFromDirectoryMapper gets loaded but not AbstractJob. Both are included (MAHOUT_INTEGRATION  MAHOUT_CORE respectively)

Comment: I'm almost out of guesses on this one.  Can you see if the jar actually gets copied to the node (does it exist at that location while the job is trying to run)?